# javascript adding object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrayobject

```
this.journeyIds = ["source", "destination"];
this.journeyDetails = [];

this.journeyIds.map((id)=>{
    this.journeyDetails.push({
        id: this.el("#" + id).inputValue
    });
});
```

I want array like [{Source : "LMP"}, {Destination : "LKO"}];
i.e I want to make Id as key in object

thank you!

Comment: This isn't really clear enough to understand

Comment: please paste your code in https://jsbin.com for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want the id as key of an object. Use `[]` around the id

```
this.journeyIds = ["source", "destination"];
this.journeyDetails = [];

this.journeyIds.map((id) => {
                this.journeyDetails.push({[id] :
this.el("#"+id).inputValue});
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the function `this.el()` so it's an array here, you could just replace it with the function call (`this.el["#"+id].inputValue` => `this.el("#"+id).inputValue`

```js
this.journeyIds = ["source", "destination"];
this.journeyDetails = [];
this.el = {
  "#source": {inputValue: "foo"},
  "#destination": {inputValue: "bar"}
}

this.journeyIds.forEach((id) => {
    let temp = {};
    temp[id] = this.el["#"+id].inputValue;
    this.journeyDetails.push(temp);
});

console.log(this.journeyDetails)
```